# from the 18th to / until 30th of July

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if you could help me to fill in the blank below using the proper preposition. Meanwhile I need to know the reason(s) of using one over another (In case one of these choices has privilege upon the other one.)
- I went to a French course from the 18th..........the 30th of July.
a) to
b) until

Answer (score 2):

Both could be correct depending on usage.  My feeling is this:

"to" puts the empahsis on the dates, the 18th and the 30th.

"until" puts a subtle emphasis on the duration or time in between, 12 days.

"through" is another alternative but is more appropriate for a future time span, eg. "I will be taking a French course from the 18th through the 30th of July."